# how to make css tooltip not push elements outline in FF

Tags: css, firefox, tooltip

I'm following the example posted [here](http://css-tricks.com/6555-css-content/) for making custom css tooltips.

```
a {
  color: #900;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
  position: relative;
}

a[title]:hover:after {
  content: attr(title);
  padding: 4px 8px;
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 99;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #eeeeee),color-stop(1, #cccccc));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
}
```

I am wondering if there is a way to not have the tooltip push out it's parent elements `outline` in FireFox, it seems to work fine in Chrome

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    outline: 2px solid #F00;
}
```

[see example here](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/HgeVh/)

Comment: +1. Good question. Can't see a solution to it apart from not using `outline`.

Comment: I think my next question would then be how to suppress the default *tooltip* generated by the title attribute. or is there a way in css to attach to an elements dataset? `a[data-title]:hover:after`

Comment: that might be worth asking in a separate question.

Comment: ahh, it is. [see here if you are interested](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/HgeVh/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how you can possibly fix this. I wonder if this is a Firefox bug?

The only thing that comes to mind is to use `box-shadow` instead of `outline`:

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/HgeVh/9/

This has the downside that you're losing the outline in IE8, if that matters.

Comment: The outline is nice, but purely stylistic. If IE8 cannot see it i'm not too bummed.